# Plot the CIFAR10 Dataset classes frequency on pytorch

Tags: python, plot, dataset, pytorch

I would like to visualize the number of image data for each class of the cifar10 dataset on a graph.I have tried implementing this on pytorch but I couldn't get any satisfying results.
Can anyone please help me to plot the CIFAR10 Dataset classes frequency on pytorch.

Here is an exemple of an implementation i have tried but i keep getting an error when comparing labels with the classes indexes, and the plot function seems to work pretty well

```
def classes_freq():
    for images, labels in trainloader:
          #print(labels.shape)
      
          images = images.to(device)
          labels = labels.to(device)
          count = [0]*10
          for i,e in enumerate(classes):
            if (labels.item() == i):
              count[i]+=1
    return count

classes_freq()

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot(y_units):

  x_units = ['plane', 'car', 'bird', 'cat',
           'deer', 'dog', 'frog', 'horse', 'ship', 'truck']

  plt.bar(x_units, y_units,width=0.8, color=['red','blue'])

  plt.xlabel('x - axis')
  plt.ylabel('y - axis')
  plt.title('classes frequency')

  plt.show()

#plot([10,20,23,50,60,70,80,90,10,45])
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried ? Provide some code and tell us what your blockers are :)

Comment: I edited the post.